# How to replace() something variable between curly brackets {...}?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Suppose the following string in JavaScript,

```
str = "{This is between curly brackets}, {but I don't know what is between the brackets...}"
```

Then how do I replace() the part between the curly brackets?

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked for you?

Comment: And could you give an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: Did you even make an attempt to find a solution before coming here? Google has over a million hits on how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Text Inside of Curley Braces JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334380/replacing-text-inside-of-curley-braces-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (regex) to achieve that.

Just use string's replace function. The first parameter will be the regex and the second one the content you want to replace all the occurrences.

```
str.replace(/\{[^\}]+\}/g, '{replacement}'); //"{replacement}, {replacement}"
```